# ImageView Change Listener in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

How can I set up a change listener for an ImageView's image property?

```
//dstOne is an ImageView
dstOne.imageProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            public void changed() {

            }
        });
```

Comment: `dstOne.imageProperty().addListener((o, oldImage, newImage) -> { /* ... */ });`

Comment: @VGR thanks, sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public void changed()` is not the correct method signature for the ChangeListener interface.  The `image` property is not a Boolean either. Fix that. This is the interface method:

`void changed(ObservableValue<? extends T> observable, T oldValue, T newValue)`

For the image property the type (`T`) is Image.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#imageProperty

Using any decent IDE, the correct method signature could have been completed for you.